# Xcode 11 completion behaviour for project in C++

Tags: c++, xcode11

I'm struggling to change the behaviour of auto-completion for my own project in Xcode11. 
I selected an empty project and I have implement some C++ methods. Now I want Xcode to recognize these methods and show the auto-complete suggestions for them.
However, I am only getting completion suggestions for basic C++ code, e.g., if-else, switch case, etc.. How can I setup Xcode to recognize my own methods?

Besides, in an older Xcode version I got auto-complete suggestions for previously written text in the same file. This functionality is gone. Can I reactivate it somehow?

Cheers

Comment: I had the same problem recently, unfortunately I did not find any solution for enabling code completion for c++ code. I recommend to use another IDE/Editor for c++ code (e.g. CLion or VSCode)

Answer (score 0):

Your project *should* index and make those methods available in auto-completions. I've had similar issues (currently Xcode 11.3.1), but I found that building the project once (even with just a boilerplate main function), quitting and restarting Xcode seemed to help, at least for the project-local classes & methods. However auto-complete is broken now for some parts of C++, as if the standard system search paths for C++ aren't getting indexed. For example, completions for standard C++ header #includes (e.g. ) don't appear, only various Apple C lib headers. It may be that manually adding these paths to the build settings could resolve them. It used to "just work" though.

I'd also recommend filing a bug report if you haven't already. I'm sure they're focused mostly on Swift these days but if enough reports come in they may fix it.